# Vuetify 3 collapses `v-list-item when` `to` attribute is used

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

With `to`:
[image]

Without `to`:
[image]

Here's the code:

```js
   <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer">
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" :title="item.title" :to="item.value">
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
```

here's the items array

```js
items: [
        { title: 'Tenets', value: 'tenets' },
        { title: 'Units', value: 'units' },
        { title: 'Charges', value: 'charges' },
        { title: 'Payments', value: 'payments' }
      ]
    }
```

Any thoughts or experience on what causes this?

Comment: You'll need to provide enough code to make the issue reproducible.  Basic navigation drawer example using your code does not show any issue as seen in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/gOBBRwx?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `:to`, `<v-list-item>` renders a `<div />`. With a valid `:to`, it renders an `<a />`.

Most likely, you have some CSS which applies to `div.v-list-item` and does not apply to `a.v-list-item`.

Without a *runnable* [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ***nobody*** can help, as we have no way to determine which part of the code you are not sharing is responsible for the output difference in rendering.

We can only inspect code, not pictures.

Comment: I bootstrapped my project through amplify and the `vue createApp` cli.   Apparently one of those added some styles to App.vue that were' incompatible with Vuetify.